# Pass setState as props or create a handle

Tags: reactjs

Can I pass the `setPlaying` as props? Or I have to do something like this example code?

Components `Two` and `Three` can be in their own file.

```
export const myComponent = () => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (show) => {
    setPlaying(show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <One />
      {!playing ? (
        <Two handleChange={handleChange} />
      ) : (
        <Three handleChange={handleChange} />
      )}
    </>
  ) 
};

const Two = ({ handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Button onClick={{(e) => handleChange(true)}}>Click to Show Component Three</Button>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Three = ({ handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Button onClick={{(e) => handleChange(false)}}>Click to Show Component Two</Button>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes you definitely can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  Wrapping `setPlaying` with `handleChange` is advantageous if you wish to do any further processing in `myComponent`.  And the conditional rendering will prevent needless re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Also, it is a good practice that you did with the handler.

ref: [Passing setState to child component using React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850845/passing-setstate-to-child-component-using-react-hooks)